# Why does LuaJIT not print with `-mavx2`?

Tags: compiler-flags, luajit

I am trying to write a Lua binding for a C library with LuaJIT's C ffi, but encountered this problem.
LuaJIT doesn't print the line, but only with `-mavx2` flag set.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Environment

   - **CPU**: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz
   - **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04, 64bit
   - **GCC** version : gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
   - **LuaJIT** version: 2.0.4
   - Actually I ran this inside the fantastic ZeroBrane Studio (Latest version)
2. test.c

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>

   uint64_t aux(const uint64_t b)
   {
       return b & b;
   }

   void test(uint64_t state)
   {

       uint64_t b[64];

       for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
       {
           b[i] = (state<<1) ^ state;
       }

       aux(b[0]);

   }
   ```
3. Compiling to a shared library

   ```
   gcc -W -Wall -Winline -g -fPIC -shared -O3 -o libtest.so test.c # without -mavx2
   gcc -W -Wall -Winline -g -fPIC -shared -O3 -mavx2 -o libtest.so test.c # with -mavx2
   ```
4. Using the library in LuaJIT

   test.lua

   ```
   local ffi = require("ffi")
   local L = ffi.load("./libtest.so")

   ffi.cdef[[
   void test(uint64_t);
   ]]
   local s = ffi.new("uint64_t", 0);
   print("Hello!")
   L.test(s)
   print("Hello!")
   ```
5. Output

   Without `-mavx2`: `hello!\nhello\n`, as expected.
   With `-mavx2`: `hello!\n`

Comment: Oh, no, seems like the CPU doesn't support the AVX2 instructions...